# Angular 5 mat-tab-group not working

Tags: angular, angular5

The mat-tab-group not working in Angular 5 project, I have installed all the required dependencies as mentioned in their documentation, I know there is already question similar to this for Angular 4, which says to install BrowserAnimationsModule, but i have tried that it is still not working,

template:

```
<div class="try">
  <mat-tab-group>
    <mat-tab label="First"> Content 1 </mat-tab>
    <mat-tab label="Second"> Content 2 </mat-tab>
    <mat-tab label="Third"> Content 3 </mat-tab>
  </mat-tab-group>
</div>
```

appModule.ts file:

```
imports: [
BrowserModule,
NgxPaginationModule,
HttpModule,
TabModule,
FormsModule,
NgxPopper ,
MDBBootstrapModule.forRoot(),
RouterModule.forRoot(
  appRoutes,
  { enableTracing: true } // <-- debugging purposes only
),
BrowserAnimationsModule,
MatTabsModule,
MatTableModule,
```

Comment: What is not working? Do you get a blank screen? Do you get any error messages? Are the tabs there, but formatted improperly? Have a look at the example provided by Angular: https://run.stackblitz.com/api/angular/v1?file=app%2Ftab-group-basic-example.ts

Comment: the screen is blank, but when i go through the inspect element , i can see blank highlighted tabs

Comment: Does your web browser's console display any information?

Comment: Try to add theme in your styles.css as - @import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css";

Answer (score 3):

[Try solution](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pgrrka)

HTML:

```
<mat-tab-group >
  <mat-tab label="Short tab">
    <div class="example-small-box mat-elevation-z4">
      Small content
    </div>
  </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Long tab">
    <div class="example-large-box mat-elevation-z4">
      Large content
    </div>
  </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { MatLabel } from '@angular/material';
import {MatTabsModule} from '@angular/material/tabs';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';



import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HelloComponent } from './hello.component';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule,BrowserAnimationsModule,MatTabsModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, HelloComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

style.css:

```
@import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css";
```

Answer (score 0):

You should specify a height for the div that encapsulates the mat-tab-group element as below. Otherwise, the mat-tab-group content is not visible.

```
<div style="height:100%">
 <mat-tab-group>
 ....
 </mat-tab-group>
</div>
```